# Fatal error: Call to undefined method JUser::authorize()

Tags: php, templates, joomla, upgrade

I upgrade my joomla 1.5 website to 3, and there is a problem that when I install old oringinal template, the index page shows:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method JUser::authorize() in /volume1/web/2016-rhim-new/templates/ja_purity/html/com_content/article/default.php on line 6
```

and the code on line 6 is:

```
<?php if (($this->user->authorize('com_content', 'edit', 'content', 'all') || $this->user->authorize('com_content', 'edit', 'content', 'own')) && !$this->print) : ?>
<div class="contentpaneopen_edit<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' )); ?>" >
    <?php echo JHTML::_('icon.edit', $this->article, $this->params, $this->access); ?>
</div>
```

Please help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Juser::authorize() has been removed. Use JUser::authorise() instead.

At this page you can find all [potential backward compatibility](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1) for Joomla 3.

Also consider to ask **Joomla related questions** on [joomla.stackexchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) to get better answers!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Removed the templates/TEMPLATE/html/com_content/default.php file, and everything is now working properly.

But in This You may loss your html structure. Because In that template file is for the joomla 1.5 and now there is many changes in new joomla.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for you answer! 
But I can't find "default.php" in the "com_content" folder, my template is ja_purity 1.20 and there are just "article", "category", "frontpage", "index.html", "section" in the "com_content" folder.

Comment: Yes sorry there is little wrong path. It is in the folder of the com_content view (article, category, frontpage, etc) In that you can found the file. Before delete please Take backup. Or give me access so i can fix it.